# Can I learn anything about a misfiring cylinder from the fact that the dialectric grease around the plug is discolored?

Tags: misfire, diagnostics

[image: discolored cylinder]
[image: normal cylinder]

On the way to the in-laws yesterday my 2008 fusion started bucking. Code reader says I'm misfiring on cylinder 2. I popped off the coil boots thinking I'd swap them and see if the problem cylinder swapped; however when I got the boots off I realized the problem child was visibly discolored. I don't see sign of oil/coolant intrusion in either cylinder, so I don't think it's mixing.

Is there anything valuable I can learn from this before I tear further in?

Comment: Perhaps there is a slight leak from around the plug or perhaps the valve cover gasket has allowed a slight bit of oil through to contaminate the grease.  Either way, the issue appears to be very slight and is unlikely to be the problem here.  I'd proceed with checking the plug and coil and see if you can identify the problem.

Comment: You could check if the coil on cylinder 2 produces any spark by using a test spark plug and ground it to the engine block. I'm assuming your car has a coil on plug setup...